# Angular 8, Firebase Showing users based on collection of UID's

Tags: angular, firebase, filter, view

I need a little help around this. Tried to investigate and did multiple tries where I end up either with the last user collection or the first, in any case I cannot return/view all.

I have for example 4 UID's and I need to show users that match those 4 UID's out of lets say 50 users.
I tried using `this.db.list('users/', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(<string>id.ids)).snapshotChanges()` but this returns only the user that match the last value/UID.

Is there a chance of achieving this in any way possible without loosing on performance too much ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example as Stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending few hours I finally came up with a solution, I execute this code on ngOnInit:

```
  this.auth.user.subscribe(user => {
  this.db.list('users/' + user.uid + '/friends').valueChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
    return changes.map(x => {
      return x;
    })
  })).subscribe(friends => {
    let test1 = [];
    let test2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < friends .length; i++) {
      this.db.list('users/', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(<string>friends[i].ids)).snapshotChanges()
        .subscribe(x => {
        test1.push(x);
        test1.forEach(y => {
          y.forEach(z => {
            test1 = [];
            test2.push(z);
            this.friendsList$ = test2;
          })
        })
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Based on these 4 uids shown on the image below, I am fetching all user profiles with all the data needed for each user, to create a list of users that I am connected with.

[image]

and at the end in the template I use friendsList$ in the *ngFor loop.

**Note:**
This is code can be refactored and done better, this is my first solution. After the refactor I will edit this answer. This is just in case someone had the same issue.